# How to run Filezilla on XAMPP?

Tags: filezilla, xampp

when i try to start filezilla on XAMPP, there is message "Attempting to start FileZilla service..." and nothing happens, how can i fix it?

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srbHS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you posted says it all, filezilla is not found in the location where the management console thinks it should be located.   Did you move filezilla after the installation?

[image]

Have you tried to edit the control panel config for FileZilla to point at

`c:\program files\xampp\filezillaftp\filezillaserver.exe`
I think by default the XAMPP installer tries to install itself into c:\xampp, but it appears for some reason it is installed in your program files folder.

If that does not work, try configuring filezilla to run on a port other than 21 and then try to start the service, it is a possibility you might be running ftp or some other application on that port and it is not able to start since that port is already in use.   The only reason I suggest this as a possibility is the error message that says `uninstall/disable the other service manually first`, but that might just be a reference to the path being incorrect.

Comment: Please mark my answer as the correct response to resolve this question.  That way other people having this issue can quickly identify the right solution.  Glad I could help!

Comment: @LevaniQotolashvili please mark my answer as the solution for this issue if it resolved your problem.